# Displaying markers instantly when loading in cluster?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, clustering

I am loading a big json for about 10000 pins with some text, about 3-4mb.
And it takes some time to load all the pins and display them.

Is there a way to diplay the pin right after loading?

So to see the progress of pins loading?

Here is my jquery json loading

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'api.php',
         data: {},
         success: function(data) {

             data.map(function(item) {

                 var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng), {
                         icon})
                     .bindPopup(content)
                     .on('click', function(e) {
                         console.log(marker);
                     });
                 clusterMarkers.addLayer(marker).addTo(map);
                             })
                      },
         //contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: 'json'
     });
```

**Update:** the answer and example is here https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#chunked-addlayers-options